# Error using xlswrite

Tags: matlab, xls

So I have this piece of code.

Forward =

```
ForwardDifferentiation(a, eq, deltaX);
    Backward = BackwardDifferentiation(a, eq, deltaX); 
    Central = CentralDifferentiation(a, eq, deltaX); 
    SecDeriv = second(a, eq, deltaX); 
    ThirdDeriv = third(a, eq, deltaX);
    FourthDeriv = fourth(a, eq, deltaX); 

    fprintf('y'' using Forward Difference @x=%g is: %.5f', a, Forward);
    fprintf('\ny'' using Backward Difference @x=%g is: %.5f', a, Backward);
    fprintf('\ny'' using Central Difference @x=%g is: %.5f', a, Central);
    fprintf('\ny" using Second Derivative @x=%g is: %.5f', a, SecDeriv);
    fprintf('\ny"'' using Third Derivative @x=%g is: %.5f', a, ThirdDeriv);
    fprintf('\ny"" using Fourth Derivative @x=%g is: %.5f', a, FourthDeriv);

    filename = 'NumericalDifferentiation.xlsx';
    A = {'y''(Forward Diff)', 'y''(Backward Diff)', 'y''(Central Diff)', ...
    'y"', 'y"''', 'y""'; Forward, Backward, Central, SecDeriv, ...
    ThirdDeriv, FourthDeriv};
    xlswrite(filename,A) % Writing an xls file
```

But errors always occur about the xlswrite:

Error using xlswrite (line 220)
The file C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin\MP2a\NumericalDifferentiation.xlsx is not
writable.  It may be locked by another process.

and

Error in NumDif (line 66)
        xlswrite(filename,A) % Writing an xls file

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If the `.xls` file is open somewhere, it does not allow to write the file. Close the `.xls` file from all the programs and then try to run the code.